# ImportError: cannot import name 'mailparser' from 'lib'

Tags: python

I downloaded a repository which other people are using. This file works for everyone else except for me so I believe there is a problem with my local setup.

There is a line `from lib import mailparser` which is causing the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 3, in <module>
    from lib import mailparser
ImportError: cannot import name 'mailparser' from 'lib' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib/__init__.py)
```

There is 100% a file called 'mailparser' in the 'lib' directory but it isn't recognizing it.

From the error it seems to be looking in the `usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lib` which has to be wrong as the correct path is `/Users/myname/Documents/Company Name/parser/lib/mailparser.py`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/2102076

Answer (score 0):

If that's where you've downloaded the `lib` package to, then you'll need to do

```
sys.path.insert(0, "<PATH-TO-PACKAGE>")
```

at the top of your file to get Python to look in there for it.

The problem here is that you have a package called `lib` that already exists in your `site-packages` folder, which is where Python looks for files to import. In the case of your colleagues, they have nothing, so Python falls-back to looking in the current working directory for something called `lib`. In your case, it finds this random `lib` and uses that. To avoid that, you tell Python to look at your current working dircetory first, by inserting it into the first position of your `sys.path`.

If the repository you've downloaded has a `setup.py` file, you might be expected to go into the repo and run `pip install .` to install from source. This will install the code into your `site-packages`.

Comment: No one else has had to do this though. I'm more than sure it is a problem with my setup.

Comment: If you downloaded the repo, is it a python package? You might need to go into it and run `pip install .` so it installs from the `setup.py` into your `site-packages`.

Comment: No it is has been written by us

Comment: Then the problem seems to be that you have already have a package called `lib` in your `site-packages` unlike your colleagues, that don't, so Python looks through the current working tree for something called `lib` and finds it, but in your case, it looks through site-packages first, sees lib and thinks that's what you mean. Either `pip uninstall lib` or do the `sys.path` trick.